# How does the Litecoin difficulty get calculated?

Tags: litecoin, difficulty-retargetting

Bitcoin creates 2016 blocks, and if the average time of 2016 blocks is less than 10 minutes, the difficulty increases. If it is more than 10 minutes, the difficulty decreases.

How does the Litecoin mining difficulty get adjusted?

Comment: It is actually 2016 blocks in Bitcoin per difficulty retargeting. (The first block is not accounted for due to an off-by-one error)

Answer (score 1):

Litecoin is a fork of Bitcoin Core, and uses the same difficulty adjustment period (2016 blocks), which on Litecoin is 3.5 days because the block time is 2.5 minutes instead of 10.  See [chainparams.cppL#85](https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecoin/blob/master/src/chainparams.cpp#L85):

```
consensus.nPowTargetTimespan = 3.5 * 24 * 60 * 60; // 3.5 days
consensus.nPowTargetSpacing = 2.5 * 60;
```